# Cannot Import Javascript File To html.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am trying to import a file called ng-infinite-scroll.min.js in a html.erb file (titled application.html.erb).  I know .erb stands for embedded ruby.

Giving the absolute path to the file like so causes an error:

```
<script src="/Users/username/Nasiki/app/assets/javascripts/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

The error reads out in the console:

```
"GET http://localhost:3000/Users/username/Nasiki/app/assets/javascripts//ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"
```

Note that I am running this server locally and so the home for my website is:

```
http://loclhost:3000
```

Why can't it find this file given the absolute path.  I've tried a lot of different paths, it may have to do with how .erb files accept paths.  Does anybody know?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<% javascript_include_tag 'ng-infinite-scroll.min' %>
```

Below is the documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Do I not need to include the .js at the end? thanks!

Comment: Hi so, just as a sanity check I tried putting something non-sensical in the quotations like 'ng-infinite-asdfafsd-scroll.min' and I do not see an error in the console when the page loads (using chrome).  Is there a way that you know of that I can be sure this file is loading in my webpage?  I'm quite new to javascript so my apologies for the noob question.  thanks

Comment: Do you use chrome? You could see it on the network panel on the DevTools. See a pic here http://i.stack.imgur.com/S8mGP.png

Comment: oh wow, yep that worked.  Sweet, I appreciate the help.  Such nice people on on stack overflow